# How to read and use data from CSV files?

Tags: c

I have CSV files that contain 2 columns of x and y coordinates, that are the positions of particles.

I want to read these files and be able to use the data inside to calculate a function (I mean I want use the coordinates to calculate the pair distribution function *g(r)*).

I have the algorithm to calculate this function but I need help with how to access the CSV files, and be able to read and use the data inside. I'm new to programing in C, can anyone help?

Comment: Are those coordinates in integer or float format? Can you copy and paste a couple of lines? It's very easy to read a CSV file but need to know if its integer or float data. See fscanf which allows you to read formatted data from a stream/file.

Comment: float format 258.80435 463.3913
397.07144 437.17346
299.2073 463.42682
387.05814 456.94186
299.2073 463.42682
316.56976 446.77905
399.61627 456.61627

Answer (score 4):

You use a library, such as [libcsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/).